# How to set dimensions jquery UI selectmenu?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I can't find a way to set the dimensions of a jqueryUI selectmenu specifically. I'd like it to be 150x40px. I managed to set its width to 150px by using:

```
$( "#brandstof" ).selectmenu({
  width: 150
});
```

But as there is no 'height' option there (as far as I know), I then tried to set the height to 50 with this css:

```
.ui-selectmenu-button-closed,
.ui-selectmenu-button-open {
  border: 1px solid black !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  color: #aaa !important;
  height:50px !important
}
```

Which increases the height but too much. It then is about 99px high. With both the selectmenu text and icon at the top instead of the vertical center.

It then looks like this:

[image]

The width is ok, but the height is larger than the set 50px. And both the button text and icon not vertically centered.

You can view my attached in below Codepen:

[jquery selectmenu codepen](https://codepen.io/coder1965/pen/eYxyBKM)

Comment: Please [edit] and post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the jQuery-UI `selectmenu` does not have a `height` option, likely because it was implemented with a `<SPAN>` tag.

It's possible to hack it though.

We address it by changing the CSS for `ui-selectmenu-button-open` class.

1. To fix the excessive height you need to change `box-sizing` to `border-box` so it accounts for the padding (which is non-zero).
2. To center text and icon vertically we can simply increase the top padding by adding `padding-top: 17px !important;`

```js
 $( "#brandstof" ).selectmenu();

   $( "#brandstof" ).selectmenu({
    icons: { button: "ui-icon-caret-1-s" },
position: { my: "left bottom", at: "left bottom" } 
 });

$( "#brandstof" ).selectmenu({
  change: function() {
//change font color .ui-selectmenu-text to black
$( ".ui-selectmenu-text" ).css( "color", "black" );
  }
});

$( "#brandstof" ).selectmenu({
  width: 150
});
```

```css
body{
  font-family: Arial;
}

#dropdown-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 100;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.ui-selectmenu-text {
  font-size: 12px !important;
}

.ui-selectmenu-button-closed,
.ui-selectmenu-button-open {
  border: 1px solid black !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  color: #aaa !important;
  height: 50px !important; /* added missing semicolon */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* fix height, account for padding */
  padding-top: 17px !important; /* increase top padding to move text and icon a bit lower */
}

.ui-state-active {
  background-color: #ccc !important;
  border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
  color: black !important;
}

.ui-widget-content {
  font-size: 12px !important;
  color: #333 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdown-container">
   <label for="brandstof">Fuel</label>
   <select name="brandstof" id="brandstof">
      <option value="petrol" selected>Gasoline</option>
      <option value="diesel">Diesel</option>
      <option value="electric">Electric</option>
      <option value="hybrid">Hybrid</option>
   </select>
</div>
```